# Trying to send a styled email from a form

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to send a email from a form.I wanna style email body.I have store all field values 
in different variables and calling them in another variable to collect and send to email which i have set to receive emails. My code is for collecting field values,

```
$body = "
First Name: $name \n\n
Last Name: $LastName \n\n
Email: $email \n\n
Telephone: $Telephone \n\n
Country: $Country \n\n
City: $City \n\n
State: $State \n\n
Zip Code: $Zip \n\n
Address: $adress \n\n
";

//and here is code from where i am receiving emails which is working fine.

$headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
$emailSent = true;
```

if i put html tags around the variable for example

> `<div class="">Zip Code: $Zip </div>`

inside  variable

`$body = "";`

it display same in the email inbox with html tags.How i have to style email body this way.Thanks

Comment: You just want stylize your form? Create html and add style in style tag

Comment: Not sure which emails you will be sending this to but GMAIL absolutely does NOT let you use classes, everything needs to be inline-style, and even if you do use all inline styles then their parsing algorithm will screw up the output. Yahoo will allow you to declare internal style sheets and classes but their parsing algorithm will also screw things up. Just accept it that you will be using `<table>` and weep quietly. Good luck!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus he said that mail is displayed with HTML tags inside (treated as text/plain). You need change your content type to `text/html` as I said below to use HTML tags inside your message. But MonkeyZeus is right that Gmail forbids to use class="" parameter, you should use `style="(style here)"` instead.

Comment: @TomaszBanasiak Yes I saw your great answer, it is why I chose to provide additional information that could save Waseem many hours of hair-pulling frustration later

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert `Content-type:` header to your headers, like:

```
$headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
$headers .= "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html';
```

and that's it!

Comment: Well i am doing all in wordpress.

Comment: Thank you so much friend.I am trying.I will let you know.

Comment: Perfect.Everything is fine.Thank you so much @ Tomasz Banasiak

Comment: one more help can you answer my question here? 
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116471/a-attachment-file-with-a-php-form-in-wordpress